# Car overheating and car smells like coolant

Tags: overheating, heater, heater-core

Yesterday I was driving normally when my car suddenly started to overheat. A bit of smoke is coming out from the vent. Suddenly the car stopped and I have a damp passenger side foot rest. Could this be indicator of heater core fault or leaking ??

Answer (score 3):

What you described is very much an accurate representation of a leak in the cooling system, localized to the heater core. The smell in the cabin is particularly telling. One can hope that no damage was done to the engine by the overheat condition, but you should have it towed to a repair shop to ensure the damage is not increased.